# Very large permutation

Tags: permutation, shuffle, large-data

Let's say I want to generate all numbers between 0 and x at random without ever generating twice the same one.

A naive way of doing this would be to generate numbers at random and check whether they have already been used or not. However, as time progresses you'll get more and more duplicates and the generator will slow down.

Another way one could do this, is by filling an array with all numbers between 0 and x and shuffle (permute) them.
However, when X gets sufficiently big, it's no longer feasible to do this (both for storage and computational restrictions).

Is there a way to generate the elements lazily?

Comment: Check out Linear Feedback Shift Registers: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_feedback_shift_register